# What is there to spend my rupees on?

Tags: zelda-link-to-the-past

I'm playing through the Legend of Zelda: A Link to the Past. By the time I got the first pendant, I was already maxed out on my rupees (999) and bought the empty jar. Is there anything else to spend my rupees on? Like any new items or increasing my capacity for bombs or arrows? I just got the master sword and am still in the same predicament.

Comment: When a "A Link to the Past" question shows up when they are running the game on AGDQ. Perfect timing.

Comment: @Isuka What's AGDQ?

Comment: Games Done Quick, a one week charity gaming marathon for The Prevent Cancer Foundation. Anyway, do you want an answer for the moment you are in right now in the game, or do you want a list of what can be interesting to buy with rupees in the whole game?

Comment: @Isuka I'd like an answer for the moment. It's just been a waste getting rupees now that I'm maxed and I figure I'll be able to max out again if I spend them anyways.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### [Flippers](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Zora's_Flippers) for 500 Rupees

It sounds as though you don't have this item yet, and it's easily the biggest use of Rupees in the game. If you head to the northeastern most part of the world map, you can find a path leading north to an area full of Zoras. If you go all the way to the end, you can find a giant Zora who will offer to sell you the Flippers for 500 Rupees, allowing you to swim.

However, like most Zelda games, you'll usually end up maxing out your wallet early and often. There's just not that many significant things to spend your money on.

Answer (score 34):

I would say that the [Pond of Happiness](https://zeldawiki.org/Pond_of_Happiness) is a good place to spend rupees.  You can find the pond inside a cave on an island in the middle of Lake Hylia.  You will need to buy [Zora Flippers](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Zora's_Flippers) from Zora in Zora's Lake for 500 rupees in order to swim to reach the island.

Depositing 100 rupees allows the player to increase their bombs or arrows carrying capacity by 5 for each 100 rupees deposited.  You can do this up to a maximum of 50 bombs and 70 arrows (with the last upgrade for each being an increase of 10).

It looks like you can only throw in either 5 or 20 at a time, unless you have met Venus, in which case, it is 25 or 50.

> At first, Link can only throw in 5 or 20 Rupees at a time. After he meets Venus, the amounts increase to 25 and 50 Rupees.

Besides this, there is no way to increase the carrying amount of how many rupees you can hold.  It's [only 999 for a Link to the Past](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Rupee).

Comment: Can you clarify how I can get to the pond of happiness at my point in the game? The wiki doesn't explain that. As far as I can tell I need a boat or something to make it to the island.

Comment: @spacetyper see my edit. You'll need Zora Flippers which you can purchase for 500 rupees from the river leader Zora in Zora's lake - just another way to use your money!

Comment: You first need the power gloves from the desert palace in order to get to Zora.

Answer (score 13):

### Blue Potions, 160 - 640 Rupees

When you get to the later dungeons, You'll want to stock up on potions, and a lot of them. Both magic and health can run low as the difficulty increase. You can get 4 jars for holding potions. There is a magic shop close to Zora's waterfalls, where you can get three kinds:

- Blue Potion -        160 Rupees
- Green Potion -     60 Rupees
- Red Potion -         120 Rupees

refilling four jars with blue potions will cost you 640 rupees, and at this point in the game, you might use them fast, and not have as many richly filled treasure chests available for plundering.

Comment: I keep my jars full of fairies. The revival effect is just too powerful.

Answer (score 2):

Full guide to Shop Costs and Shop Locations.

--

***Shop Costs:***

--

**Rupee costs for 100% items:**

Bottle costs 100 rupees.

Flippers cost 500 rupees.

Kiki first asks for 10 rupees to follow you, and then 100 rupees to open PoD.

The capacity-upgrading faerie requires 800 rupees to max out bombs, and 800 rupees to max out arrows.

**Potion shop:**

Red Potion: 120 Rupees

Green Potion: 60 Rupees

Blue Potion: 160 Rupees

**Light World shop:**

Red Potion: 150 Rupees

Single Heart: 10 Rupees

10 Bombs: 50 Rupees

**Dark World shop:**

10 Arrows: 30 Rupees

Bee: 10 Rupees

Fire Shield: 500 Rupees

**Dark world Bomb Shop:**

30 Bombs: 100 Rupees

SuperBomb: 100 Rupees (Only after getting crystals 5 and 6 (Ice Palace and Misery Mire))

--

***Shop Locations:***

--

**Bottle:**

Bought from merchant in Kakariko Village

**Flippers:**

Bought from the Big Zora (Top right of map, Light World)

**Kiki:**

In the Dark World Hedge Maze (Right side of map)

**Capacity-upgrading faerie:**

In the middle of Lake Hylia (Bottom Right of map, Light World)

**Potion Shop:** Flute warp #2, between Zora Waterfall and Eastern Palace

**Light World Shops:**

In Kakariko Village, Small house in the south

Eastern Death Mountain

Lake Hylia North Cave

**Dark World Shop:**

Thieves Town

**Dark World Bomb Shop:**

Dark world equivalent of Link's House